# Dynamic Change TeplateUrl

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

> I am trying to make `templateUrl` dynamically, but it seems to return
>   URL string in UI.

Here is my code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: '../login/'+Setting.URL+'/login.html',
  // templateUrl: '../login/web/login.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
});
```

**The issue is, that the template url does not read the html file location.**

Answer (score 0):

The correct aproach of dinamic url is by **deep linking**, using always the same html template but with diferent information.

In your router:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login/:name',
    component: LoginComponent,
  }
];
...
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
```

In your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: '../login/web/login.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
});

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
) {
  this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
    console.log(params.name);
  });
}
```